# How to merge duplicate values keys into one array with php

Tags: php

```
 $newVar =   Array  
    ( 
        [a] => Array
            (   
                [0] => php    
                [1] => sql
            )
        [b] => Array
            (
                [0] => javascript
                [1] => c
            )
        [c] => Array
            (
                [0] => php
                [1] => sql
            )

        [d] => Array
            (
                [0] => c++
                [1] => java  
            )    
    )
```

In above multidimensional array, how to merge duplicate values with keys into one array like this below,

```
$newVar =   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => a    
                [1] => c    
            )   
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => b
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => d
            )    
    )
```

I tried below but its only remove duplicate keys

```
$new = array_keys(array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $newVar))));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new);
```

How to merge the duplicate key in multidimensional array in php..?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array of keys from the concatenation of values.

```
$newVar =   [
  'a' => ['php','sql'],
  'b' => ['javascript','c'],
  'c' => ['php','sql'],
  'd' => ['c++','java'],
];

$result = [];
array_walk($newVar, function($val, $key) use(&$result){
  $result[implode("",$val)][] = $key;
});
```

The interim result looks like this:

```
array (
  'phpsql' => 
  array (
    0 => "a",
    1 => "c",
  ),
  'javascriptc' => 
  array (
    0 => "b",
  ),
  'c++java' => 
  array (
    0 => "d",
  ),
)
```

You can then get the desired result with array_values​​().

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

[Try self (Sandbox)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/336ae4413d802e81bc6e7b04715ce5c580b5a7b0)